# How to make this responsive card be mostly bigger?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to create a very simple design:

- a card (image + title + some text)
- a button (simple button that is
  fixed in the bottom of any screen)

Now requirement is to make sure it renders great on most popular modern devices (iPhone, iPad, Androids but also if opened on PC)

This is what I did so far:

```css
div.cardContainer {
  position:absolute;
  max-width:60%;
  max-height:60%;
  top:45%;
  left:55%;
  overflow:visible;
}
div.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  position:relative;
  max-width:80%;
  max-height:100%;
  margin-top:-50%;
  margin-left:-50%;
}
.card-img {
  position:relative;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
.card-title {
  padding-left: 16px;
}
.card-text {
  padding-left: 16px;
}
.buttonContainer {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardContainer">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img" src="http://placehold.it/560x560">  
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula utasdasdasdasdas dasdas asdasd asdasd asd as id elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="buttonContainer" type="button">Button</button>
```

It sort of works but a I can not resolve the following:

on mobile devices (where width is smaller than height) - the card is too small, I need it to be "spreaded" around a bit more, so that it tried to occupy most of the space but was still always centered both vertically and horizontally.

This is supposed to be a "walkthrough" intro card and I can't figure how to make it look good on majority of devices. Any advice?

Comment: Media queries have nothing to do with it, this is because of the % you're using.

Comment: Yah I figured as well, but I am still puzzled as to why all this is so complicated;) I am trying a few things now but unsure what I do

Answer (score 0):

OK this is what I wanted and it worked great across all devices (using devtools). I did not optimize this for horizonal (16:9) type of layout. This looks good though for all portrait layouts.

```css
div.cardContainer {
        position:absolute;
        top: 5%;
        left: 5%;
        right: 5%;
        bottom: 10%;
        overflow:hidden;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      }
      div.card {
        position: relative;
        height: 90%;
        width: 80%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
        margin: auto;
      }
      .card-img {
        padding-top: 16px;
        max-width:100%;
        max-height:560px;
      }
      .card-body {
        position: relative;
      }
      .card-title {
        padding-left: 16px;
      }
      .card-text {
        padding-left: 16px;
        padding-right: 16px;
        padding-bottom: 16px;
      }
      .introNextButton {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="cardContainer">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img" src="http://placehold.it/560x560">  
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula utasdasdasdasdas dasdas asdasd asdasd asd as id elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <button class="introNextButton" type="button">Button</button>
```